# What is the difference between string:byte and string:binary in a Azure Logic Apps custom connector?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

What is the difference between string:byte and string:binary in a response field in an Azure Logic Apps custom connector, see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [OpenAPI Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types):

```
byte    string  byte    base64 encoded characters
binary  string  binary  any sequence of octets
```